# Is there a way to detect if a QML property is bound (not set to a static value)?

Tags: qt, qml

Is it possible to tell the difference between a property that is set to a static value vs. a property that is bound to something else? I checked documentation, but don't see anything about this.

```
Rectangle {
    id: firstRect
    color: "black"  // set to static value
}
Rectangle {
    color: firstRect.color  // bound to external value
}
```

In this example, can I detect that the firstRect color is a static value, whereas the second rectangle color is bound?

Comment: It would be interesting to know what is your use case for this. Debugging? Something else? If this isn't possible (and I kinda suspect it isn't), maybe there is another way to achieve what you need.

Comment: I'm exposing the properties of a control in so a user can modify them at run time in a sandbox environment. It would be nice to be able to tell a user if the default value of a property is a binding or just a static value, as well as be able to restore the original binding or value if overwritten among other things.

Comment: As far as I remember, it is possible to find the slots connected to a Signal. I haven't performed any experiments, but maybe it is possible to search all property-changed-signals, and find out whether they trigger a change on some other property.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're after is in a private static method: [`QQmlPropertyPrivate::binding()`](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtdeclarative/src/qml/qml/qqmlproperty.cpp.html#_ZN19QQmlPropertyPrivate7bindingERK12QQmlProperty).  For example here is some QtQuick Designer code [using it](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtdeclarative/src/quick/designer/qquickdesignercustomobjectdata.cpp.html#251).

Being technically in the Qt private parts, I'm not sure this helps.  Interestingly, the `Qt::QML Type` has a [`Qt.binding()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-qt.html#binding-method) function which is used to assign bindings (and apparently calls the above private method behind the scenes). And there is the QML [`Binding`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-binding.html) type. But in neither case do I see a way to get an instance of an existing binding (`QAbstractBinding`) already assigned to a property.

Responding to some of the comments: Through the Qt meta object system you can find what is connected to a property notifier signal. But to do that you'd need to know the `QObject` and `QMetaProperty` to which the QML property in question is bound to (or not)... which brings us back to square 1 I believe (finding out what the property is bound to, if anything).